# C - struggling to understand how to use int function within if/ while loops

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop, cs50

So I'm doing CS50 and struggling with an error that occurs when I include the following two lines:

```
 if (int i < (number -1)) 

 if (int i =< number)
```

when compiling, 'error: expected expression' comes under 'int'. Am I using it incorrectly within while if statements?

Comment: `int` is not a function.  What do you mean by `use int function`?

Comment: `=<` is not valid C.

Comment: `int i` declares a variable but leaves it uninitialized.  `int i = 5` declares a variable and initializes it.  `int i < 5` is a syntax error.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Show a [mcve]. The two lines as they are in your question is not a valid C program.

Comment: Answer for "Am I using it ..." is "No." What you want maybe `if (i < (number - 1))` and `if (i <= number)`.

Comment: @MikeCAT Your comment-edit overlapped with me creating my answer. I hope you do not mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can not declare variable in an if statement. But if you want your variable in a local scope you can create a block and declare your variable, initialize it and use. We have to use <= for checking less than or equal to instead of =<
example:

```
{
  int i =5,number=10;
  if(i < number-1)
  {
   //Add your code
  }
  if(i <= number)
  {
   //Add your code
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks so much this has solved my issue - still getting used to how things are structured in code. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

`int i;` is a variable declaration/definition.
That confuses your compiler when it tries to understand your `if` condition.

I have to guess a little, but am confident. You probably want

```
if (i < (number -1)){ /* assuming code here */ }

if (i <= number)    { /* assuming code here */ }
```

Note that is also changed `=<` to `<=`.

Comment: thanks this has fixed it :) thanks so much!